# Border over selected cells

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to have a yellow border just over the top of my grid cells minus the first two cells(home button and search). I've tried a couple scenarioes.

This is the application header without any borders.

http://snag.gy/2lIIm.jpg

This is the application when I specified borders over the grid items. The problem with this is that it stops and doesn't extend to the end.

http://snag.gy/pVbHd.jpg

The picture below extends to the end but it's also ontop of item 1 and 2. I'm trying not to have a border on the first two items.

http://snag.gy/6QiX9.jpg

If I can possibly get help with this issue please.

WorkTabView.xaml

Border over selected buttons but not extended to the far right -  Pseudo Code

```
<Grid>
    ....
    <Button-Home Grid.Column0>
    <AutoCompleteBox Grid.Column1>        
    <Border BorderBrush="Yellow" Grid.Column=2 BorderThickness="0,1,0,0">
        <Button1/>
    <Border/>
    <Border BorderBrush="Yellow" Grid.Column=3 BorderThickness="0,1,0,0">
        <Button2/>
    <Border/>
<Grid>
```

Border over everything, but my goal is not to have over search and home button Pseudo Code

```
<Border BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0">    
    <Grid>
        ....
        <Button-Home Grid.Column0>
        <AutoCompleteBox Grid.Column1>        
        <Button1 Grid.Column2/>            
        <Button2 Grid.Column3/>             
    <Grid>
</Border>
```

Sorry for Pseudo code, posted it to prevent lengthy post and repetitions. My goal is to have the border around everything BUT the search and yellow home button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options here.

Use your Option1, but place an extra item to fill the rest of the remaining space.

```
<Grid>
    ....
    <Button-Home Grid.Column0>
    <AutoCompleteBox Grid.Column1>        
    <Border BorderBrush="Yellow" Grid.Column=2 BorderThickness="0,1,0,0">
        <Button1/>
    <Border/>
    <Border BorderBrush="Yellow" Grid.Column=3 BorderThickness="0,1,0,0">
        <Button2/>
    <Border/>
    <Border BorderBrush="Yellow" Grid.Column=3 BorderThickness="0,1,0,0">
        <SomeBlankItemToTakeUpRemainingSpace/>
    <Border/>
<Grid>
```

If this is used, I would definitely see about creating a custom style or template for the border to avoid repeating myself

Alternatively, split the two sections up into two separate panels, and store them in another panel that has the default behavior of filling all available space, like the DockPanel

```
<DockPanel>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Right">
        <HomeButton>
        <SearchBox>
    </Grid>
    <Border> <!-- this is last item in DockPanel, so should stretch to fill all available space -->
        <Grid>   
            <Button1 Grid.Column1/>            
            <Button2 Grid.Column2/>             
        <Grid>
     </Border>
</DockPanel>
```

Personally I prefer the second option. LayoutControls in WPF are meant for laying out your controls, not for creating tables of items, so to me this seems like the cleaner approach.

Comment: Thank you @Rachel, Example 2 is definitely the best option and is very clean.